# R - overestimation predict function in sinusoidal linear model

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction, forecasting, predict

**Background**

I have a data file which consists of Sea Levels near the Dutch Storm Barrier over time, for various days. The goal is to fit a linear model that describes this evolution of the sea level, and given a certain time frame, make a 5 minute ahead-prediction of the sea level (forecasting).

**Approach**

Given a certain day (chosen on forehand), I chose a time frame on which I want to fit\train the linear model. After some technical adjustments (see below for actual code), I fitted the model. Then, the linear model object and 5 minutes time range are used in the command 'predict()' for a prediction, and the 'forecast' along with a confidence interval is graphed, just behind the fitted model in the first time frame, all in one plot (see below for an example plot).

**Problem**

The forecast of the model always over- or under predicts hugely. In terms of magnitude, the forecast is a factor 10^10 (or, equivalently, e+10) off. At the same time, the R^2 and R_adj^2 are 'quite high', (0,972 and 0,9334, respectively) and the model diagnostics (leverages, fitted vs residuals, normal qq) look 'reasonably good'. Hence, my problem/question is: How can the model that fits the data so well, predict/forecast so badly? My only explanation is mistake in the code, but I can't spot it.

**The data set**

More specifically, the dataset is a data frame, which consists (apart from a index column) of 3 columns: 'date' ( "yyyy-mm-dd" format), 'time' ( "hh:mm:ss" format) and 'water' (integer between approx -150 and 350, sea level in cm). Here's a small slice of the data which already gives rise to the above problem:

```
> SeaLvlAug30[fitRngAug, ]
        date       time       water
1574161 2010-08-30 04:40:00   253
1574162 2010-08-30 04:40:10   254
1574163 2010-08-30 04:40:20   253
1574164 2010-08-30 04:40:30   250
1574165 2010-08-30 04:40:40   250
1574166 2010-08-30 04:40:50   252
1574167 2010-08-30 04:41:00   250
1574168 2010-08-30 04:41:10   247
1574169 2010-08-30 04:41:20   246
1574170 2010-08-30 04:41:30   245
1574171 2010-08-30 04:41:40   242
1574172 2010-08-30 04:41:50   241
1574173 2010-08-30 04:42:00   242
1574174 2010-08-30 04:42:10   244
1574175 2010-08-30 04:42:20   245
1574176 2010-08-30 04:42:30   247
1574177 2010-08-30 04:42:40   247
1574178 2010-08-30 04:42:50   249
1574179 2010-08-30 04:43:00   250
1574180 2010-08-30 04:43:10   250
```

**Minimal runnable R code**

```
# Construct a time frame of a day with steps of 10 seconds
SeaLvlDayTm <- c(1:8640)*10 
# Construct the desired fit Range and prediction Range
ftRng <- c(1:20)
predRng <- c(21:50)
# Construct the desired columns for the data frame
date <- rep("2010-08-30", length(c(ftRng,predRng))) 
time <- c("04:40:00", "04:40:10", "04:40:20", "04:40:30", "04:40:40", "04:40:50", "04:41:00", 
      "04:41:10", "04:41:20", "04:41:30", "04:41:40", "04:41:50", "04:42:00", "04:42:10", 
      "04:42:20", "04:42:30", "04:42:40", "04:42:50", "04:43:00", "04:43:10", "04:43:20", 
      "04:43:30", "04:43:40", "04:43:50", "04:44:00", "04:44:10", "04:44:20", "04:44:30",
      "04:44:40", "04:44:50", "04:45:00", "04:45:10", "04:45:20", "04:45:30", "04:45:40", 
      "04:45:50", "04:46:00", "04:46:10", "04:46:20", "04:46:30", "04:46:40", "04:46:50",
      "04:47:00", "04:47:10", "04:47:20", "04:47:30", "04:47:40", "04:47:50", "04:48:00", 
      "04:48:10")
timeSec <- c(1681:1730)*10
water <- c(253, 254, 253, 250, 250, 252, 250, 247, 246, 245, 242, 241, 242, 244, 245, 247, 
       247, 249, 250, 250, 249, 249, 250, 249, 246, 246, 248, 248, 245, 247, 251, 250, 
       251, 255, 256, 256, 257, 259, 257, 256, 260, 260, 257, 260, 261, 258, 256, 256,
       258, 258)
# Construct the data frame
SeaLvlAugStp2 <- data.frame(date, time, timeSec, water)
# Change the index set of the data frame to correspond that of a year
rownames(SeaLvlAugStp2) <- c(1574161:1574210)
#Use a seperate variable for the time (because of a weird error)
SeaLvlAugFtTm <- SeaLvlAugStp2$timeSec[ftRng]
# Fit the linear model
lmObjAug <- lm(SeaLvlAugStp2$water[ftRng] ~ sin((2*pi)/44700 * SeaLvlAugFtTm)
           + cos((2*pi)/44700 * SeaLvlAugFtTm) + poly(SeaLvlAugFtTm, 3)
           + cos((2*pi)/545 * SeaLvlAugFtTm) + sin((2*pi)/545 * SeaLvlAugFtTm)
           + cos((2*pi)/205 * SeaLvlAugFtTm) + sin((2*pi)/205 * SeaLvlAugFtTm)
           + cos((2*pi)/85 * SeaLvlAugFtTm) + sin((2*pi)/85 * SeaLvlAugFtTm), 
           data = SeaLvlAug30Stp2[ftRng, ]) 
# Get information about the linear model fit
summary(lmObjAug)
plot(lmObjAug)
#Compute time range prediction and fit
prdtRngTm <- timeSec[prdtRng]
ftRngTm <- timeSec[ftRng]
#Compute prediction/forecast based on fitted data linear model
prdtAug <- predict(lmObjAug, newdata=data.frame(SeaLvlAugFtTm = prdtRngTm), interval="prediction", level=0.95)
#Calculate lower and upper bound confidence interval prediction 
lwrAug <- prdtAug[, 2]
uprAug <- prdtAug[, 3]
#Calculate minimum and maximum y axis plot
yminAug <- min(SeaLvlAug30$water[fitRngAug], SeaLvlAug30$water[prdtRngAug], lwrAug)
ymaxAug <- max(SeaLvlAug30$water[fitRngAug], SeaLvlAug30$water[prdtRngAug], uprAug)
#Make the plot
plot((timeSec/10)[ftRng], SeaLvlAugStp2$water[ftRng], xlim = c(min(timeSec/10), max(prdtRngAug30)), ylim = c(yminAug, ymaxAug), col = 'green', pch = 19, main = "Sea Level high water & prediction August 30 ", xlab = "Time (seconds)", ylab = "Sea Level (cm)")
polygon(c(sort(prdtRngTm/10), rev(sort(prdtRngTm/10))), c(uprAug, rev(lwrAug)), col = "gray", border = "gray")
points(prdtRngTm/10, SeaLvlAug30$water[prdtRngTm/10], col = 'green', pch = 19)
lines(ftRngTm/10, fitted(lmObjAug), col = 'blue', lwd = 2)
lines(prdtRngTm/10, prdtAug[, 1], col = 'blue', lwd = 2)
legend("topleft", legend = c("Observ.", "Predicted", "Conf. Int."), lwd = 2, col=c("green", "blue", "gray"), lty = c(NA, 1, 1), pch = c(19, NA, NA))
```

**Example plot**

[Sea Lvl High Water & prediction August 30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu2WF.png)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Without the value for `SeaLvlAug30`  we can't copy/paste the code to run it. If the code is only for `SeaLvlDayTm[fitRngAug]`, then just edit your example to use that smaller dataset and make your example complete.

Comment: I have seen something similar to the modeling results you have described when I have overfit my data, so I have a suggestion for a test to try. As a test, first fit the data in your post to a straight line, then - one at a time - add in the additional terms in your model.  The straight line alone should of course give bad results, which should improve as each term is added without the large over- and under-predicting. *If* overfitting occurs you should then see see the over- and under-fitting behavior. Easy test.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @MrFlick I added a (arguably simple) reproducible example with sample input that resembles the real data I have.

Answer (score 0):

Until you post a question with code that we can run we won't be able to help you more but in the meantime here is a quick and dirty forecast from Rob J Hyndman forecast package:

```
string_data <- "row date       time       water
1574161 2010-08-30 04:40:00   253
1574162 2010-08-30 04:40:10   254
1574163 2010-08-30 04:40:20   253
1574164 2010-08-30 04:40:30   250
1574165 2010-08-30 04:40:40   250
1574166 2010-08-30 04:40:50   252
1574167 2010-08-30 04:41:00   250
1574168 2010-08-30 04:41:10   247
1574169 2010-08-30 04:41:20   246
1574170 2010-08-30 04:41:30   245
1574171 2010-08-30 04:41:40   242
1574172 2010-08-30 04:41:50   241
1574173 2010-08-30 04:42:00   242
1574174 2010-08-30 04:42:10   244
1574175 2010-08-30 04:42:20   245
1574176 2010-08-30 04:42:30   247
1574177 2010-08-30 04:42:40   247
1574178 2010-08-30 04:42:50   249
1574179 2010-08-30 04:43:00   250
1574180 2010-08-30 04:43:10   250"

SeaLvlAug30 <- read.table(textConnection(string_data), header=TRUE)

library(forecast)

fit <- auto.arima(SeaLvlAug30$water)
summary(fit)

preds <- forecast(fit, h = 25)
preds
# Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
# 21       249.7563 247.7314 251.7812 246.6595 252.8531
# 22       249.4394 246.1177 252.7611 244.3593 254.5195
# 23       249.1388 244.9831 253.2945 242.7832 255.4944
# 24       248.8930 244.2626 253.5234 241.8114 255.9746
# 25       248.7110 243.8397 253.5822 241.2610 256.1609
# 26       248.5867 243.6073 253.5661 240.9713 256.2021
# 27       248.5085 243.4867 253.5302 240.8284 256.1885
# 28       248.4636 243.4280 253.4991 240.7624 256.1647
# 29       248.4410 243.4020 253.4800 240.7345 256.1475
# 30       248.4322 243.3927 253.4718 240.7249 256.1396
# 31       248.4311 243.3916 253.4707 240.7238 256.1385
# 32       248.4337 243.3941 253.4733 240.7263 256.1411
# 33       248.4376 243.3979 253.4773 240.7300 256.1452
# 34       248.4414 243.4016 253.4812 240.7337 256.1492
# 35       248.4447 243.4048 253.4845 240.7368 256.1525
# 36       248.4471 243.4072 253.4870 240.7392 256.1550
# 37       248.4488 243.4089 253.4887 240.7409 256.1567
# 38       248.4499 243.4100 253.4898 240.7420 256.1578
# 39       248.4505 243.4106 253.4905 240.7426 256.1585
# 40       248.4509 243.4109 253.4908 240.7429 256.1588
# 41       248.4510 243.4111 253.4910 240.7431 256.1589
# 42       248.4510 243.4111 253.4910 240.7431 256.1590
# 43       248.4510 243.4111 253.4910 240.7431 256.1590
# 44       248.4510 243.4110 253.4909 240.7430 256.1589
# 45       248.4509 243.4110 253.4909 240.7430 256.1589

plot(preds)
```

[image: forecast]